# Como configurar URL para centralizar objeto

Tags: css, html5

Fiz uma navbar que ao clicar em um item ela redireciona para a mesma página para uma div que possui o atributo id,porém o site fica com  navbar em cima do texto

```
<li>
   <a href="#Especialidades">Especialidades</a>
</li>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível eu configurar algo para que ao clicar no item fique assim?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não tem código javascript, quero fazer que com a navbar não fique em cima do Titulo: "Especialidades"

Comment: Coloque um `padding-top: 30px;` na div "Especialidades" que resolve.

Comment: @DvD Valeu, manda como resposta para eu marcar

Comment: Que bom que resolveu! Já mandei a resposta. Abs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione um `padding-top: 30px;` na `div` "Especialidades" que resolve o problema de espaçamento superior.

Answer (score 0):

caso o link seja interno na pagina , coloque no inicio do local(na foto ta como "especialidades") e adicione um margin top do tamanho da navbar

Comment: Não entendi, como assim?